# How to remove java.sql.BatchUpdateException in Grails?

Tags: java, grails

I have a Domain like

```
class BusinessOrganization {

    static hasMany = [organizationBusinessTypes:OrganizationBusinessType]

    String name
    String icon

    static constraints = {
        name(blank:false,unique:true)
        icon(unique:true)
    }

    String toString() {
        return "${name}"
    }

}
```

While saving the first time the data is saved with no error. But when I tried to save second time I get this error:

```
Class java.sql.BatchUpdateException Message
Batch entry 0 insert into business_organization (version, icon, name, id) values ('0', '', '', '2') was aborted. Call getNextException to see the cause.
```

It says :

```
def save() {
23:        def businessOrganizationInstance = new BusinessOrganization(params)
24:        if (!businessOrganizationInstance.save(flush: true)) {
25:            render(view: "create", model: [businessOrganizationInstance: businessOrganizationInstance])
26:            return
27:        }
```

Error at line 24. I am unable to figure out what I have done wrong. In other domain this works fine. Please someone help.I am new to Grails and now stucked here. I am using PostGreSQL

Answer (score 0):

Try entering

```
insert into business_organization (version, icon, name, id) values ('0', '', '', '2')
```

directly into your database (in console or pgAdmin) and check for exceptions.

Also mind that you put unique constraints on name and icon values - check those in your saved entry.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the save (line 24) in a try/catch and give the appropriate feedback to the view layer